# "disable" on_change id odoo 9 after creating product

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

I'd like to ask, if is there any way to "disable" onchange decorator, when product is already created.

I have a field (X), which value depends, what will be in the 3 another fields (Y). I've used "api.onchange". When product is created, i want to make, that one of Y fields, will not change a value of X anymore.

I tryed to check, if "self" is existing in database, like exists(), but even new record is marked as "existing". I tryed to get access to self.id, but it's impossible. I thought about create additional field with Boolean type, but it's the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW API**

First picture i added an onchange event to the name of `product.template` i used debug mode to stop the program and see if i have an acces to `self._origin` clearly i have access to it

[image]

Second picture it shows when I updated a product the ID value is passed

[image]

Now Third picture shows when i'm creating a new Product the value of the `id` in `self._origin` is False

[image]

so can you post the code that use used please i want to understand why you don't have acccess to self._origin

**OLD API**

when using old api self._origin is not access but you have the list of ids in edit mode the list will not be empty .

```
def onchange_name(self, cr, uid, ids, name, context=None):
        # when updating a record ids will not be empty
        # in my case will be ids=[55]
        # in create mode the ids is empty
        # id = []
        if not ids :
             # here you are in create mode you put your logic here
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Odoo doesnt recognizing self._origin. If i'm trying to use it, 
then odoo says, that `'product.template' object has no attribute '_origin'`.
I have tryed `if isinstance(self._origin, models.NewId) or isinstance(self._origin.id, models.NewId)` and simply `print(self._origin)` and odoo is crashing on this line, no matter if im trying to create new product or edit existing one.

Comment: checks my edits my question how did you implement the onchange event